# JavaScript: parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I parsed this JSON:

```
foobar({
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/pHRM7wJ9wmWClTcY53S4FP4-Iho\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "regionCode": "PL",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 686,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/hpaieEHTq-SS7i8XR2SdBPqendk\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "j6r_N251pNQ"
   }, "width": 480,
          "height": 360
         }
        },
        "channelTitle": "arhn.eu",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
       }
      },
```

My code (`json_string` contains the above JSON):

```
var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json_string));
alert(json['foobar']);
```

How can I get `videoId` value?

Comment: Why do you stringify before parsing it? Thats not JSON, by the way, thats JSONP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach it with:

```
json['foobar']['items']['id']['videoId']
```

Just nest it :)